# Segregating a Map in two map based on value in Groovy or java

Tags: java, groovy, collections, java-8, hashmap

I have a map of type Map<Object,ArrayList> MapA.
map can have values like

```
MapA
{key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34 , value = ["12345","Complete","5431"],
key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71 , value = ["2311","InComplete","5321"],
key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71 , value = ["4567","InComplete","4321"],
key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51 , value = ["2345","Complete","5432"]}


output should be 

MapA
{key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34 , value = ["12345","Complete","5431"],
key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51 , value = ["2345","Complete","5432"]}

MapB
{key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71 , value = ["2311","InComplete","5321"],
key=0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71 , value = ["4567","InComplete","4321"]}
```

I want to create a new MapB from MapA having all key value pairs, where value has "InComplete" in it. Either i can have two extra map having "Complete" and "InComplete" KeyValue pairs or if i can remove Incomplete from MapA.

So i want to Segregate MapA on the basis of Complete or InComplete into two seperate maps.

I need to write it in groovy but if i can get some hint in java 8 as well, i can try to convert it.

Code snippet i am working on but this will create new Map but won't remove these values from MapA, how can i do that?

```
MapA.entrySet().stream().filter(entry->entry.getValue().get(1).equals("InComplete")).collect(Collectors.toMap())
```

Appreciate your help

**UPDATE**

```
 def mapB = [:].withDefault {key -> return []}
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, ArrayList>> iterator = mapA.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Object, ArrayList> entry = iterator.next();
        if(entry.getValue().get(1).equals("InComplete")) {
            mapB.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
            iterator.remove()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi @tgdavies, I am stuck with the part of removing values from MapA while creating MapB. I am very new to groovy so not exactly sure how to approach this wrt to groovy syntax. I can add my code snippet

Comment: Since you put "or in Java" - How would you do it in Java? Hint: I'd iterate over the entry set, check the values and if they are incomplete remove them from the iterator and put them into the new map.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, i have added my part of code which i have written i java, but i am not sure how to remove the value while creating new map.

Comment: Don't use streams here as they won't allow you to modify the underlying source. Instead use a traditional loop and an iterator (`for(Iterator<Object> itr = mapA.keySet().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) { /*your body*/ }`). Alterantively remove the keys you put into mapB after using the stream.

Comment: @Thomas won't removing any value from map while iterating will cause concurrent modification exception?

Comment: Not if you're using the iterator's `remove()` method which is built to handle this kind of situation. Just don't change the map via other means while using an iterator.

Comment: @Thomas, edited my question and added the code, can you tell me if its correct?? i can't run it right now due to lack of data.

Comment: Looks reasonable

Answer (score 2):

There are thousands way of doing this.

Down below I put 3 options: 1 with filling 2 maps independently in 2 loops, 1 (slightly better performing) using the single loop, and 1 using `groupBy`:

```
def map = [ '0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34':["12345","Complete","5431"],
'0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71':["2311","InComplete","5321"],
'0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71':["4567","InComplete","4321"],
'0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51':["2345","Complete","5432"]]

// 1. option
Map complete = map.findAll{ k, v -> 'Complete' == v[ 1 ] }
Map inComplete = map.findAll{ k, v -> 'InComplete' in v }
assert complete.toString() == '[0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34:[12345, Complete, 5431], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51:[2345, Complete, 5432]]'
assert inComplete.toString() == '[0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71:[2311, InComplete, 5321], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71:[4567, InComplete, 4321]]'

// 2. option
def twoMaps = map.inject( [:].withDefault{ [:] } ){ res, curr ->
  res[ curr.value[ 1 ] ] << curr
  res
}
assert twoMaps.toString() == '[Complete:[0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34:[12345, Complete, 5431], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51:[2345, Complete, 5432]], InComplete:[0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71:[2311, InComplete, 5321], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71:[4567, InComplete, 4321]]]'

// 3. option -> credits to @tim_yates!
def groupMaps = map.groupBy{ it.value[ 1 ] }
assert groupMaps.toString() == '[Complete:[0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34:[12345, Complete, 5431], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51:[2345, Complete, 5432]], InComplete:[0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71:[2311, InComplete, 5321], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71:[4567, InComplete, 4321]]]'
```

Comment: Or: `map.entrySet().groupBy { it.value.contains('Complete') }` to end up with a map containing "true" for contains Complete, and "false" for those that don't

Answer (score 2):

And for fun, this is the same but in Java 17

```
var stringListMap = Map.of(
        "0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34", List.of("12345", "Complete", "5431"),
        "0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71", List.of("2311", "InComplete", "5321"),
        "0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71", List.of("4567", "InComplete", "4321"),
        "0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51", List.of("2345", "Complete", "5432")
);

var result = stringListMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                e -> e.getValue().get(1),
                Collectors.mapping(e -> e, Collectors.toList())
        )
);
result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " => " + v));
```

Which prints:

```
Complete => [0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f34=[12345, Complete, 5431], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1r51=[2345, Complete, 5432]]
InComplete => [0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-9f71=[2311, InComplete, 5321], 0003bb2d-f3cf-4b5c-1d71=[4567, InComplete, 4321]]
```